# Background image not scrolling horizontally in tablet view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using background image on main div and different elements positioned in it. Background looks good in desktop and scrollable in mobile version. I would like to have either scrollable of overflow-x in tablet or full view of image in tablet.

When i apply overflow-x:scroll; to the div that has background, i'm able to scroll things on top of it but not background itself.
I tried background-attachment: scroll; it is not working. and background-size: cover is also not working.

What is the best way to tackle this?
What is the media query i can use to make same view for mobile and tablet?

P.S:  I'm using two different images for desktop and mobile. I could use either of the images for tablet.

This what i've in tablet view for main div

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.virtual {
     background-image: url(/*****/stage);
     background-position: center -30px;
     min-height: 500px;
}
```

This what i've in mobile view for main div

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.virtual {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

This what i've in mobile view for inner div(of main div)

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.hotspot-container {
    background-image: url(/****/stage-sm);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1341px 768px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 1341px;
    top: 2px
}
```

Comment: Have you tried applying overflow-x:scroll; to the container of the div that has background?

Comment: yes, i did. But didn't work. Only the item inside the div are scrolling not the background itself.